# Bootstrap Carousel Caption Center Align

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm not trying to do anything too fancy here, but instead of the Bootstrap Carousel Captions defaulting to aligning to the bottom of the Carousel, how do I get them to default align to the top?

Comment: could you post your current code in your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the code, I can only guess - right now you have:

```
<div class="carousel-item">  
<img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">  
<div class="carousel-caption">  
<h3>Los Angeles</h3>  
<p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>  
</div>  
</div>
```

*source: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp)*

simple reordering may work, if not show us the code

```
<div class="carousel-item">  
<div class="carousel-caption">  
<h3>Los Angeles</h3>  
<p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>  
</div>  
<img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">  
</div>
```